# JSHint error: myApp is not defined (W117)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why i have this error with jshint ..? :

> JSHint: 'myApp' is not defined. (W117)

***My app.js:***

```
myApp = angular.module('autoApp', ['ngRoute', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ngTable', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/cars.html',
                controller: 'AutoAppCtrl'
            }).when('/contact', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/contact.html',
                controller: 'ContactCtrl'
            }).when('/services', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/services.html',
                controller: 'AutoAppCtrl'
            }).when('/carDetails/:id', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/carDetails.html',
                controller: 'CarDetailsCtrl'
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because...`myApp` is not defined. Add a `var` in front of it to declare it. Otherwise, you're relying on [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (which only "works" in loose mode anyway), so JSHint is quite rightly telling you not to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The error describes the problem perfectly. `myApp` is not defined. Define it with

```
var myApp
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you need to use `var myApp` there instead of myApp only.

Secondly you don't need to.

Even if you use `var myApp`, a global variable would be created. To avoid it, use `angular.module('autoApp')` (no second argument) wherever you want reference to myApp.